# И снова однородные члены при обобщающем слове

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли оформлено следующее предложение?

Так что с арматурой я не расстаюсь по сей день, хотя уже 3 года работаю в «глянцевом» журнале: беру интервью у генеральных консулов, аккредитованных в С.-Петербурге, перевожу статьи для журнала, бываю на презентациях, приемах, выставках, дефиле — в общем, веду светскую жизнь.

Answer (score 1):

Знаки препинания расставлены верно.

Старшая конструкция -  БСП со значением пояснения.

Первая часть - СПП с придаточным уступительным. Вторая часть - однородные определенно-личные предложения с обобщающим предложением в конце (оформление по образцу однородных членов при наличии обобщающего слова).

Answer (score 0):

Грамматика-то нормальная, но у вас получается, что работать в журнале означает вести светскую жизнь. )))

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, речь идёт именно о "глянцевом" журнале. А знаки препинания все расставлены верно.